# Rescue Kit 3.4: bootable USB

Tags: linux, boot

I am a new member on this site. My problem is this: I am trying to create a multiboot and put Trinity Rescue Kit 3.4 inside, but for some reason when I boot it, it is showed the following picture

[image: screenshot]

What should I do? I tried WinSetupFromUSB, Xboot, Multiboot, but nothing did the right job. I want to put inside the bootable usb these: Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Trinity Rescue Kit, Windows 7, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it OK now?

Comment: You 're right. What about now?

Comment: OK. I have no experience with this subject so I cannot help you; but these basic issues with your question I was talking about are no more, this increases the chances someone else will.